# How to set default value from int on Angularjs <select>

Tags: angularjs

How can I set a default value on a `<select>` from an integer?

```
<select ng-model="fav.Type">
      <option ng-repeat="type in data" value="{{ type.type }}">{{type.text}}</option>
 </select>
```

My data looks like this `{"text":"ABC", "type":0}`
and fav.Type returns an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ngOptions`, then simply set the model value:

```
<select ng-model="fav.Type" ng-options="item.type as item.text for item in data"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.fav.Type = 0;
```

Comment: This does not work for me. My data holds three objects, 0-2. fav.Type = 2. The list gets all three values but it is blank as default.

Comment: @JohanMagnusson -- Try `fav.Type = "2";`

Comment: @JohanMagnusson -- Mind making a plunkr to replicate?

Comment: I created a fiddle and your code worked just fine. Now I don't know what to do. But thank you!

Comment: The problem was my data, i have quotes around text like this {"text":"ABC"...} But removing those quotes it works just fine. {text:"ABC"...}